# How to give more RAM to a VirtualBox VM on a Mac

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I have around 16GB of RAM on my Mac, and I'm running VirtualBox.  I'd like to give the VM more than the 4GB of RAM it's limited to – say, I want to give it 8 GB or more of my available RAM.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can change the amount of assigned memory in the VM's settings under *System » Motherboard*.

[image]

Comment: The weird thing is that it only allows me to have a maximum of 4GB while I have like 16GB of ram in my Mac. :(

Comment: What operating system is your VM running @Ali?

Comment: @slhck the Virtualbox running on Mac OS X 10.6.8

I've tried with all the OS and the only max ram I get it is 4GB :(

Comment: No, I mean the virtual **machine** (i.e. the guest system), not your host. @Ali

Comment: Oh, How to check that @slhck ??

Comment: @Ali It should say so on the *General* tab. But **you** should know what operating system you want to install in the VM ;)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg the operation I'm installing is CentOS. I'm going to check that now.

Comment: @Ali: You need to be as *exact* as possible. For example, "CentOS 5.8 i386" or "CentOS 4.9 x86_64".